# Microsoft Graph API IN n a Web Forms application

Tags: webforms, microsoft-graph-api

I want to use Micrsosoft Graph Api in a web forms application, although there are only tutorials of Microsoft Graph API in a console application or MVC applications.

I saw this tutorial explaining how I can use the Web Api in a web forms applications. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms

I wonder if the same logic will work with Graph Api. Do I have to create a model and controller in Web forms to use Graph Api?

I hope I explained it well.

Can someone advise please?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call graph api in your c# project, then you need to make sure you have an azure ad application first with the correct api permission.

Then you need to install 2 packages into your application,  and for example using client credential flow to call graph api, this is my test result.

[image]